# C# DataGridView - How to validate DGV cell if NULL button disable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hi there have a good day,
I have a problem and I can't solve it.
My problem is I have `DataGridView` and a `Button`.
When my `DataGridView` has a NULL, the button should be disabled
and when my `DataGridView` doesn't have a NULLm the button should be enabled.

I want it to happen automatically, like `textBox` to `button textChanged` event.

Like

```
DataGridView  textBox = NULL
```

When I write a value in `textBox`, the `button` will enabled automatically.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DataGridView.RowsAdded Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

You can use CellEndEdit event for DataGridView.

```
Private Sub dgv_CellEndEdit(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellEndEdit
    If dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = vbNull Or dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = "" Then
        Button1.Enabled = False
    Else
        Button1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```